# Arithmetic-geometric progression;Sn?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$S_n=1+ 3x^2+ 5x^4 +7x^6 +...+(2n-1)x^{(2n-2)}$

a)Write down the series for $x^2S_n$.

Hence show that $S_n=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)} + (2x^2)\frac{(1-x^{(2n-2)})}{(1-x^2)}- (2n-1)\frac{(x^{2n})}{(1-x^2)}$, where $x$ cannot be $\pm1$

The series for $x^2S_n = x^2 +3x^4 + 5x^6 +7x^8+...     
+(2n-3)(x^{(2n)})$

So how to show?

Comment: You have done right. The only thing which i am able to figure out is in the final answer, the second term should be $(1-x^2)^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: In the seriers for $x^2S_n$ you are missing your last term. You multiplied all terms of $S_n$ but one.

Comment: Ya you're right i've corrected it but i still can't show for Sn

Comment: @LimSookYee You are still missing the $(1-x^2)^2$ on the second denominator. Also, check my answer on how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the way to go about it:

$$S_n = 1 + 3x^2 + 5x^4 + \cdots + (2n-1)x^{(2n-2)} \rightarrow$$

$$x^2S_n = x^2 + 3x^4 + 5x^6 + \cdots + (2n-1)x^{2n}$$

Now if we subtract $x^2S_n$ from $S_n$ term by term we get:

$$S_n - x^2S_n = 1 + (3x^2 - x^2) + (5x^4 - 3x^4) + \cdots + [(2n-1)x^{2n-2} - (2n-3)x^{2n-2}] - (2n-1)x^{2n} =$$

$$= 1 + 2x^2 + 2x^4 + \cdots + 2x^{2n-2} - (2n-1)x^{2n}$$

Now, on the left hand side we factor $S_n$ out to get $(1-x^2)S_n$. On the right hand side we group the terms in 3 parts:

$$(1-x^2)S_n = [1] + [2x^2 + 2x^4 + \cdots + 2x^{2n-2}] - [(2n-1)x^{2n}]$$

Now the middle group is a geometric series:

$$G_n = 2x^2 + 2x^4 + \cdots + 2x^{2n-2} = 2(x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{2n-2}) = 2\times \frac{x^2 - x^{2n}}{(1 - x^2)} = 2x^2\times \frac{1 - x^{2n-2}}{(1 - x^2)}$$

Plugging in we have $$(1-x^2)S_n = [1] + [2x^2\times \frac{(1 - x^{2n-2})}{(1 - x^2)}] - [(2n-1)x^{2n}]$$

Now dividing both sides by $(1 - x^2)$ you get:

$$S_n = \frac{1}{(1 - x^2)} + \frac{2x^2(1-x^{2n-2})}{(1-x^2)^2} - \frac{(2n-1)x^{2n}}{(1-x^2)}$$

Comment: Okay i think i get it now thanks